# How to check the following system on existence of periodic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, periodic-functions

Let's have following system of DE:
$$
\begin{cases} \dot{x} = y(1+x - y^{2}) \\ \dot{y} = x(1+y-x^{2})\end{cases}, \quad x, y \geqslant 0
$$
How to check whether this system contains periodic solutions?

Comment: I don't have enough time to solve your problem, but the buzzwords which you should search for are poincare-bendixon and index theory, in this order.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Try some software that sketches the phase portrait of the system. For instance
[this link](http://parasolarchives.com/tools/phaseportrait). There may not be  any closed curves.

Another online phase plotter [here](http://www.bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html).

Answer (score 1):

First you should use Bendixson's Criterion to even see if it can have periodic solutions at all. Bendixon's Criterion states that if you take the divergence of this system and if the divergence never changes signs on a region $D$, and there are no holes in $D$ then there cannot be any periodic solutions in $D$. So in this case $$\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} = y + x$$ is the divergence. The actual system is easy to check for holes so that should be practice for you.

Now if you know there can exist periodic solutions. We can use the Poincare-Bendixson theorem to find out whether a region around the hole contains a periodic orbit. The way we do this is we take the dot product of the system with a normal vector to the outer hole and the inner hole, and if they have the same sign there is no periodic solution, otherwise there is. This is only if you're doing explicitly the outer normal or inner normal on both.

The general idea here is if you have a solution that is between these two 'holes', then it will always stay in between them because whenever it gets close to one of the boundaries it gets pushed off back in to the region.

Comment: Thank you! But due to my region, $x, y \geqslant 0$ (sorry, I've forgot to add this information into my question) Bendixson's criterion can't be applied, since $y + x$ is zero in point $(0,0)$. Also, there is the problem with Poincare-Bendixson theorem, since I can't define $V = x^2 + y^2 = c$ for given interval $c$ so that trajectories are trapped, and so that it doesn't contain stable fixed points.

Comment: You know that the outer normal for a circle is $(x,y)$. You're only looking for existence, so you can apply poincare-bendixsons theorem on an arbitrary 9 circle. You will get something like  $(\dot{x},\dot{y})\cdot (x,y) = y(2x+x^2-x^3) +x(y^2-y^3)$.

Comment: Yes. In order to find domain for which such quantity is negative, and by using $x^2 + y^2 = c$, $2xy \leqslant x^2 + y^2 = c$, I have
$$
\frac{c}{2}(2 + \sqrt{\frac{c}{2}} - c) \leqslant 0 \Rightarrow c \in \left(2.25+\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4};\infty\right) \equiv (c_{0};\infty)
$$
However, domain $x^2+y^2 < c_{0}$ contains stable points, so Poincare-Bendixson theorem isn't applicable.